# how to render toastr within angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, toastr

**How do you import toastr into an angular app?**

I'm following the [Angular Fundamentals](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-fundamentals&author=jim-cooper&name=angular-fundamentals-m4&clip=3&mode=live) course, and attempting to simply display **toastr.success** from within my `export class`:

```
handleThumbnailClick(eventName){
    toastr.success(eventName)
}
```

And getting the following error:

[image]

The full `ts` file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { EventService } from './shared/event.service'

declare let toastr

@Component({
    selector: 'events-list',
    template: `<div>
                    <h1>upcoming angular components</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5" *ngFor="let event of events">
                            <event-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(event.name)" [event]="event"></event-thumbnail>
                        </div>
                </div>

</div>`})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit   {
    events:any[]
    constructor(private eventService: EventService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.events = this.eventService.getEvents()
    }

    handleThumbnailClick(eventName){
        toastr.success(eventName)
    }
}
```

I've run this to install toastr:

`npm install toastr --save`

And have included these in the `angular.json` file:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't toastr render?**

Comment: for better working and usability, use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this import statement

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';
```

instead of

```
declare let toastr
```

and your  `angular.json`, it should be like this

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: that didnt seem to make any difference, the text is greyed out - showing that it is not even used

Comment: This does work, check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thuuqq) out
and my updated answer.

Comment: thanks so much, here's what i am trying: https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/AHOXsYJpxLczYgsIp6ee8An24y-ECtWv6-LjxnZKg7eJYKqnUXkRrMehx04SAjHCJH3Z2GuoSlb5-EEF6rKEBB9y-1FN3kIzjw

Comment: please keep in mind that although im a seasoned backend dev, im just starting angular so i might be missing something totally essential

Comment: The google image  is private,  i can't  see it.
can you  make a project with your  code on stackblitz  and  share the url?

Comment: please try this one https://photos.app.goo.gl/2kEXQCMDbfMnM9g1A  and i will make a stackblitz right now

Comment: use toastr.success(''); not this.toastr.success('');

Comment: can you please explain why not using `this.`

Comment: As toastr is not a class variable in the EventsListComponent class

Comment: but it's defined in the constructor `constructor(private eventService: EventService, private toastr:ToastrService) {
    }`

Comment: It's not  in the code that you provided  above, also you  need  to provide ToastrService code

Answer (score 0):

That works for me. Make sure to run :

1. `npm i --save-dev @types/toastr`
2. Add required paths in angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
]
```

3. Use `import * as toastr from 'toastr';` instead of declare let toastr